# @shared_task decorator doesn't work

Tags: django, celery, celery-task, cookiecutter-django

The problem: @shared_task decorator doesn't work, when I import data from custom files. I mean, when I start celery, all tasks under @shared_task doesn't appear in list of tasks.

For example, in this case @shared_task decorator doesn't work:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task

from .models import foo


@shared_task
def my_foo_backup(id):
    my_foo = foo(....)
    ...
    ...
```

This is example, when @shared_task works:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def my_foo_backup(id):
    my_foo = foo(....)
    ...
    ...
```

Why?!?

Comment: Did you write this code in "tasks.py"?  Certainly, Celery only recognizes "tasks.py" as a task. see also http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks

Comment: yes, of course. Other way it will not add @shared_task to list of tasks in my second example.

Comment: In the first example, can you import models.foo?

Comment: tell k, tried. That also doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to that problem was to move `import` commands inside the function. In that way it works fine and according to the rules of PEP8.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def my_foo_backup(id):
    from .models import foo

    my_foo = foo(....)
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: This fixed my problem as well but I don't understand why it makes a difference. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Some importing loop probably.

Answer (score 0):

In my case method with @shared_task was listed in celery tasks but it is not passed to broker properly(I used redis broker).
But when calling the @app.task (Note: **app** was imported from project_folder.celery.py ) decorator method inside tasks.py it was working fine.

Another solution I found was to **import project_folder.celery** inside tasks.py even though it is not used and then use the @shared_task decorator.